# How to get the time segment of a date field

Tags: acumatica

In version 5.3's Timecard Entry screen (EP305000), we had the availability to add a field to the details grid which displayed the Start Time and End Time (StartDate_Time, EndDate_Time) that sprung from the StartDate and EndDate fields.  In version 6.1 and above, there is no longer a StartDate or EndDate - but we'd like to add user fields to mimic this ability.

I've added UsrStartDate and UsrStartTime fields to the screen - but I don't know how to decorate / attribute the DAC field so that I have access to both a Date AND a time field, both relating to the same DB field as it was in version 5.3's StartDate and EndDate.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorate the Date field with the following attribute:

[PXDBDateAndTime(DisplayNameDate = "Date", DisplayNameTime = "Time", UseTimeZone = true)]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the UseSmallDateTime = true and PreserveTime = true as the defaults are false. Something like this example...

```
#region StartDate

public abstract class startDate : IBqlField { }

private DateTime? _startDate;
[PXDBDate(PreserveTime = true, UseSmallDateTime = true, UseTimeZone = false)]
[PXDefault]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start")]
public virtual DateTime? StartDate
{
    get
    {
        return _startDate;
    }
    set
    {
        _startDate = value;
    }
}

#endregion
```

The above was copied from `EPCustomWeek.StartDate`

Then in your page for the field set the DisplayFormat="g"

Comment: Nah - didn't seem to do it.  I'm looking to see both the StartDate and the StartDate_Time fields showing up in the field list to add to the grid, like they did in the 5.3 version.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I used the attribute from the new 'Date' field in ver.  6.1:

[PXDBDateAndTime(DisplayNameDate = "Date", DisplayNameTime = "Time", UseTimeZone = true)]